# event raising for combobox item selection which is inside datagrid view

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

I have a datagridcombobox column, how do I raise an event for combobox item selection?

I searched and tried the follwing code:

```
// Program.cs  
this.datagrdADDTEMP.SelectionChanged+=new System.EventHandler(datagrdADDTEMP_SelectionChanged);` 

// Form.cs
void datagrdADDTEMP_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectedGridItemChangedEventArgs e)
```

I got the following error:

```
no overloaded method for 'datagrdADDTEMP_SelectionChanged' matches delegate System.EventHandler'
```

please help me, I'm new to this concept of event bubbling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this signature

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
        System.EventArgs e)
{
    .....

}
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.clradmin.datagridcombobox_events%28v=vs.90%29

Comment: thanq so much..:) it helped a lot